# Stored Procedure only using 1 parameter instead of 2 for calculations (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a procedure that uses two `IN` parameters to make calculations. However, it seems to only use values for one of the parameters. For this example, 'gold' has a multiplier of x and 'skadite' has a multiplier of y. instead of doing the calculations with x of gold and y of skadite, it just uses the values for skadite or gold with a total of x+y. Here is the code I am working with,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sea_dew_potion2 (IN p_base_name VARCHAR(255), IN p_base_amount integer, IN p_ing_name_1 VARCHAR(255), IN p_ing_amount_1 integer, IN p_ing_name_2 VARCHAR(255),  IN p_ing_amount_2 integer, IN p_pot_units INTEGER(3)) 
BEGIN
DECLARE v_total_amount int(3);


SET v_total_amount = p_base_amount + p_ing_amount_1 + p_ing_amount_2;
    select
        p_base_name,
        p_base_amount,
        p_ing_name_1,
        p_ing_amount_1,
        p_ing_name_2,
        p_ing_amount_2,
        round(MAX((2*(2.1*(p_base_amount/v_total_amount))*(1+sqrt(p_ing_amount_1/v_total_amount)*m.multiplier_value)*(1+sqrt(p_ing_amount_2/v_total_amount)*m.multiplier_value)*p_pot_units)),3) AS heal,
        m.price * p_ing_amount_1 + m.price * p_ing_amount_2 AS cost
    FROM
        multiplier m
    WHERE
        m.ing_name = p_ing_name_1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I strongly think that the issue is with the `WHERE` clause, but i have tried doing things like `WHERE m.ing_name = p_ing_name_1 AND p_ing_name_2`, or using `or` instead of and, and even tried some weird sub queries that didnt seem to work.

For reference, i am attaching a screenshot of a `UNION` between the two different results so you can see what each result looks like, but it is not the code i think would work.

I am also posting the table that these values come from, so you can see for example that gold cost 0.05 and skadite cost .95, but instead of the total cost being 1, it is either .55 or 10.45 cause it uses 11 of one or the other, instead of 10 of gold and 1 of skadite.

[Differing results between calculations only using values of p_ing_name_1 vs p_ing_name_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwHln.png)

[Unique values between gold and skadite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDpmy.png)

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8889b99fb754e2968e396e87f02c0582).

Comment: @wchiquito looks amazing thanks! i want to put a max of 16 p_ing_name so i was just looking into how to get started. I will try to take that and mess around with it to see if i can apply it to that as well, although im not excited for 15 inner joins haha